# Difference between SSD firmware and SSD controller

Tags: solid-state-drive

I am trying to understand the difference between these two, but I did not find a clear distinction between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SSD controller is a physical chip on the SSD. The SSD firmware is the software that chip is running.

Answer (score 0):

The SSD Controller is a hardware includes an embedded processor and a memory module which is DRAM and also flash chip controllers. This controller is responsible for processing the upcoming requests and taking right actions, e.g. GC if needed, packing requests and sending requests to the right channel toward the flash chips. SSD Firmware is the software implemented in embedded processor to take care of mapping logical to physical pages (FTL), garbage collection and wear-leveling algorithm.